# What is ADS realm?

Tags: dns

I am trying to setup share in my SAN system and it is asking for ADS realm for my Domain Controller.

What is it? Where can i find this value?

I am using ActiveDirectory as domain controller.

Answer (score 2):

The ADS realm is the Active Directory domain suffix that is appended to all hosts that have joined the domain.